# How do I prevent an EntityDatasource from querying the database if the parameter is not set?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

Here is my EntityDatasource:

```
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="edsUsers" runat="server"
ConnectionString="name=kdEntities" DefaultContainerName="kdEntities" EnableDelete="True"
EnableFlattening="False" EnableInsert="True" EnableUpdate="True" 
EntitySetName="Users" AutoGenerateWhereClause="true">
<WhereParameters>
    <asp:SessionParameter Name="UsrID" SessionField="UsrID" DefaultValue="-1" Type="Int32" />
</WhereParameters>
```

I would assume I need to use the OnSelecting event of the EntityDatasource, but I haven't figured out how to check the parameter value.

I want to cancel the query if the value is -1, but I would prefer to check through the datasource and not the Session field the parameter uses.

Thanks
Kevin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may think of adding a Custom Parameter of type Object.  That can hopefully solve your problem.

```
<WhereParameters>
            <cmsParameter:CustomParameter Name="UsrID" />
</WhereParameters>
```

Then you can add a new Custom Parameter Class like

```
public class CustomParameter : Parameter
{
    protected override object Eval(HttpContext context, Control control)
    {
        MembershipUser cur_User = Membership.GetUser();
        return cur_User.ProviderUserKey;
    }
}
```

This actually gets assigned to "UsrID" custom parameter we have specified.